# Where would PhpMyAdmin be installed on my system?

Tags: mysql, netbeans, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to connect to MySQL using Netbeans. In Step 6 of [this guide](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html) on how to do so, it says:

> In the Path/URL to admin tool field, type or browse to the location of your MySQL Administration application such as the MySQL Admin Tool, **PhpMyAdmin**, or other web-based administration tools.
>   Note: mysqladmin is the MySQL admin tool found in the bin folder of the MySQL installation directory. It is a command-line tool and not ideal for use with the IDE.

So I need to find the location of the admin tool I'm using. I have PhpMyAdmin as part of the Uniform Server, so I tried to use that. But I can't find it. I manually DFS'd the UniServerX directory and couldn't find one single file which relates to PhpMyAdmin. There was a directory called "PhpMyAdmin" containing a bunch of files, none of which looked like the right ones. I did a search, and could only turn up that directory.

This is the full directory for PhpMyAdmin:

[image]

This is the form I'm trying to fill in on Netbeans:

[image]

I tried selecting "db.opt", but that wasn't the right file according to Netbeans. What should I be putting in this form? Which file singularly corresponds to PhpMyAdmin, and where should I be able to find it on my system if I have UniServer installed?

Comment: Why the close vote? How is this OT?

Comment: Does UniServer have a home page on your local system? Often this would be on localhost:8080 or something similar. It may be linked to from there. Or is there a link from the server application (where the start/stop controls are usually located, maybe in your system tray)? Also, is there any documentation for this product on this topic?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a home page. Do you mean a web application? If so, there's an index.php in the www folder. Or do you mean the UniController program, which is used to turn on Apache and MySQL?

Comment: Yes, a web application - many all-in-one *AMP packages use this as a control panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhpMyAdmin is a web interface for managing a MySQL database. I think what you are looking for is something like one of these (try them in your browser): `http://localhost/phpMyAdmin/` or `http://localhost/apanel/phpMyAdmin/`

The path in NetBeans can be configured to whatever you would like, you can even leave it blank. Its just a shortcut to open the admin console.

I would suggest setting it to UniController.exe (its in the top level folder of the UniServer installation). Through that tool, you can start/stop the server, and it has a button to open the PhpMyAdmin console.

Comment: Both of them lead to a 404 in Chrome.

Comment: The path in NetBeans can be configured to whatever you would like, you can even leave it blank. Its just a shortcut to open the admin console for you.

I would suggest setting it to UniController.exe (its in the top level folder of the UniServer installation). Through that tool, you can start/stop the server, and it has a button to open the PhpMyAdmin console. For me, the link was `http://localhost/us_opt1/index.php`. You can set that as the shortcut too if youd like. UniServer needs to be running in order for that to work.

Comment: Additionally, the folder listing you've posted for phpMyAdmin is the database for what's called the phpMyAdmin Configuration Storage -- it's a database within MySQL that phpMyAdmin uses for advanced features (note in particular that you're in the "data" subdirectory of "mysql" which is often used for storing the MySQL databases; you also appear to have databases named "mysql" and "performance_schema", both of which are used by MySQL). That's not your actual phpMyAdmin installation on disk, which would be a bunch of .php files.